# storing images on device in app-inventor

Tags: android, app-inventor

Is it possible to store images locally, on device, using app-inventor? I'd like to download some images from a website and store them locally to be able to access them when offline.

As far as I can tell TinyDB will only store text and I'm not sure what other component I could use to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, sure...
just use the **web component** to download them, [see an example how to do it here](http://puravidaapps.com/filebyfile.php)